# Quick question, do all open intervals have no endpoints or does it have infinte endpoints?

Tags: calculus, terminology

Reading Paul's Online Notes and he says that the endpoints can be solutions to optimization problems if they are **finite**. Does finite endpoint mean that the interval is closed? If so, does that mean that open intervals have infinite solutions or does it have 0?

Comment: Given that Paul's **Online** Math Notes are **online**, could you please provide a link to the page which you are reading?

Answer (score 3):

He is just saying that he is dealing with intervals of the type $[a,b]$, with $a,b\in\mathbb R$, not, say, intervals of the type $[a,\infty)$. What's *finite* here are the endpoints themselves, not the number of them.